How do I control the FQDN for my AWS load balancer?
When I create a load balancer in AWS it gets allocated a DNS name (A-record) {name-provided}-971871181.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com.
The problem is I don't seem to have any control over the -971871181 part (which changes each time), nor can I see how to create a CNAME record in ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com (or anywhere else under an AWS domain) to point to it (Hosted Zones do not work, even though AWS gives the impression they do).
But I need to be able to repeatedly tear down and re-deploy this load balancer such that it always has the same/known domain name, as I intend to use CloudFlare in front of it. CloudFlare will be configured with a CNAME record to point to the *.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com name, but I can't programmatically change that each time I re-deploy.
Surely this should be possible?


The problem is I don't seem to have any control over the -971871181 part (which changes each time),

You can't control that

nor can I see how to create a CNAME record in ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com (or anywhere else under an AWS domain) to point to it

You don't own the domain amazonaws.com. Amazon is not going to give you access to create CNAME records in their DNS servers.

Hosted Zones do not work, even though AWS gives the impression they do).

Hosted Zones work for domains that you own. You don't own the amazonaws.com domain, so you can't create a hosted zone to take control of that domain or a subdomain of that domain.
A Hosted Zone would work as your DNS server in the same way that Cloudflare is currently working as your DNS server. Since you already have DNS at Cloudflare it would not make sense to use Route53.

But I need to be able to repeatedly tear down and re-deploy this load balancer such that it always has the same/known domain name,

That's not possible. It will always have a new, random domain name each time.

CloudFlare will be configured with a CNAME record to point to the *.ap-southeast-2.elb.amazonaws.com name, but I can't programmatically change that each time I re-deploy.

Cloudflare has an API, as well as a Terraform provider. If you were using Terraform for managing your AWS resources, you could also have Terraform automatically update the Cloudflare CNAME record whenever you create a new load balancer in AWS. Otherwise, you will need to update whatever script or automation tool you are using, to make a call to the Cloudflare API to update the CNAME record when you deploy.

Our deployment script is not going to be given access to CloudFlare (not do I think it should). It seems then the only solution is to use yet another domain that we do own that we can let Route53 manage - which strikes me as rather silly (this problem doesn't exist in Azure FWIW).

You could delegate a subdomain from Cloudflare to Route53. As far as the problem not existing in Azure, send that to your AWS account rep. Nobody that can do anything about that is looking at StackOverflow.

Understood, just seems weird that you can create some resources like s3 buckets with fixed/known domain names, but not others.  As it happens I'm trying to use Beanstalk to manage the load balancers which would make it even harder, but if you can't create LBs manually with a given FQDN then it's never going to work via Beanstalk.
